# Testing Facebook application written using GWT

Tags: facebook, testing, gwt

I'm currently writing a facebook application using GWT on Eclipse, how can I test the application with all the interaction??

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how can you write tests for your whole working application, you might want to have a look at Selenium (http://seleniumhq.org/).  There are a variety of ways of using it, but essentially you can use it to automate a browser and click on elements, enter text, verify that you can see the correct result.

With GWT you will need to use "ensureDebugId" method on UiObject and add
 
to your gwt.xml file so that you get repeatable element ids that you can use in your tests.